# substitute several lines in a file with lines from another file

Tags: bash, sed

I have two files (A.txt and B.txt):

A.txt:

```
  many lines of text
  marker
  A1  A2  A3
  A4  A5  A6
  ...
  ...     AN
  many line of text
```

B.txt:

```
  some text
  B1  B2  B3
  B4  B5  B6
  ...
  ...     BN
```

I want to substitue the A1 - AN block in A.txt by B1 - BN from B.txt.
The requested result is:

```
  many lines of text
  marker
  B1  B2  B3
  B4  B5  B6
  ...
  ...     BN
  many line of text
```

I know how to find the A block:

```
grep -n "marker" A.txt |cut -f1 -d:
```

I know how to get the B block:

```
sed -n '2,+6p' B.txt
```

I might even be able write a script with something like:

```
for ...
var=$(sed -n '2p' B.txt)
sed -i "34s/.*/$var/" A.txt
```

But I'm looking for something simple and elegant

Comment: Can you determine the lines that need to be replaced (in `A.txt`) by their contents or do you just need to count them? What about the lines from `B.txt`?

Comment: I can't determine it by contents, I can only locate it's begining by content and then count.

Comment: is AN/BN always the last field on a line and is A1 and B1 always the first ?

Comment: A1 ... AN, B1...BN stands for double precision values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can start getting the filtered constent of B.txt:

  ```
   sed -n '/B1/,$p' B.txt
  ```
- Then you can append it after `marker` in A.txt with the [`r` command](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-37):

  ```
   sed "/marker/r"<(sed -n '/B1/,$p' B.txt) A.txt
  ```
- And then you can delete from `A1` until `AN` in A.txt:

  ```
   sed "/A1/,/AN/d" A.txt
  ```

**Altogheter**:

```
sed -e "/marker/r"<(sed -n '/B1/,$p' B.txt) -e "/A1/,/AN/d" A.txt
```

---

#### Example

```
$ sed -e "/marker/r"<(sed -n '/B1/,$p' B.txt) -e "/A1/,/AN/d" A.txt
  many lines of text
  marker
  B1  B2  B3
  B4  B5  B6
  ...
  ...     BN
  many line of text
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly and you know the length of the block in advance, something like this springs to mind:

```
START=$(grep -n "marker" A.txt | cut -f 1 -d:)

# Note: one more here than you want to skip, since tail and head both
# take numbers to mean including the line specified. The sed line below
# generates seven lines of output, so 8 here.
END=$(($START + 8))

head -n $START A.txt
sed -n '2,+6p' B.txt
tail -n +$END A.txt
```

Otherwise, you could use another grep statement to find the last line in the replaced block and do it just the same way.

EDIT: There was a (sort of) sign error in the original code. +$END instead of -$END is required.

Answer (score 0):

This awk should work for any size of blocks as long as A1/B1 is the first field and BN/AN is the last

```
awk '$1=="B1"{x=1}x{ss=ss?ss"\n"$0:$0}$NF=="BN"{x=0}
     $1=="A1"{y=1}$NF=="AN"{y=0;$0=ss}ARGIND==2&&!y' B.txt A.txt
```

#### output

```
  many lines of text
  marker
  B1  B2  B3
  B4  B5  B6
  ...
  ...     BN
  many line of text
```