# How to add block of code within a file?

Tags: linux, text, sed

I have this setup in some setting file:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/DS" pool-name="mysqlDS">
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DSDB</connection-url>
    <driver>mysqlDriver</driver>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>200</max-pool-size>
        <prefill>true</prefill>
        <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
        <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <security-domain>csa-encryption-sec</security-domain>
    </security>
    #block of code needs to be inserted HERE
</datasource>
```

And this is the block of code that needs to be inserted:

```
<validation>
    <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
    <background-validation>true</background-validation>
    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"></valid-connection-checker>
    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"></exception-sorter>
</validation>
```

I only had used **sed** with simples things, but I don't know how to use it properly, because I don't want to replace any text, just add the block of code inside of the other one. Any idea or suggestions ?

Comment: Don't use sed for XML processing. Use an xml tool. Like XSLT or xmlstarlet or a programming language with an xml library.

Comment: Perhaps use `awk` or XSLT

Comment: @EtanReisner, I see. I was thinking using `shell` for that but `python` should be more appropriated then.

Comment: There are tools, like xmlstarlet and XMLgawk, for interacting with XML in the shell. This situation specifically can be done with sed or awk but more complicated situations cannot.

Comment: check this out, you need something similar - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649195/adding-element-in-middle-of-xml-using-xslt

Comment: I believe that I can't use any of these suggestions guys, only sed, to avoid any kind of missing dependency among my servers.

Comment: Is this just one time activity where you want to update multiple settings files or a production activity that would happen regularly? If former, you might just use sed/awk to get it done. Just make sure to verify the results as you really would be doing just text processing instead of xml processing. You could use something like sed -i.bak -e '/<\/security>/r fileToInsert' originalFile.

Comment: @amit_g, It would be a production activity that would happen regurlarly I'm afraid.

Comment: If that is the case, don't you have to check the presence of validation element and insert it only if it is not there? If so, as advised earlier, you have to look for xml processing and not text processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sed`, you can do it with the [`r` command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236789/substitute-several-lines-in-a-file-with-lines-from-another-file/27254678#27254678) as follow:

- If you have the block of code in a file (named **validation**):

  ```
  sed "14r validation" standalone.xml
  ```
- If you have it in a variable (`$validation`):

  ```
  sed "14r"<(cat <<<"$validation") file
  ```

---

In the first method, `sed` just inserts the file **validation**.

In the second one, we have to make a file from the data in `$validation`.
A way to accomplish this is using bash's [Here Strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings) (*I noticed you are using bash in your self answer*) and [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution).
With `cat <<<"$validation"` we're supplying the expansion of `$validation` to `cat`'s standard input.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have developed so far. I'm worried if it is an intelligent approach.
Because to me, it doesn't look elegant :(

```
#!/bin/bash

validation='\<validation\> \
    \<check-valid-connection-sql\>SELECT 1\<\/check-valid-connection-sql\> \
    \<background-validation\>true\<\/background-validation\> \
    \<valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"\>\<\/valid-connection-checker\> \
    \<exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"\>\<\/exception-sorter\> \
\<\/validation\>'

sed -i "15i $validation" standalone.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

how often do you need to do this? (i.e., is that validation something that is enabled/disabled constantly?).

How about git? Just use a source-control system, then you can have a version of the file with the extra block and another one without the extra block.

Just an idea.

Comment: Hi Marcelo, thanks for the suggestion. I don't know if would be a good idea, because other configuration may be necessary to be added, and doing that for every case would may cause some trouble.

Comment: no problem, just bouncing ideas, thanks for not downvoting. So, in this case.. why not parametrize AND use git? e.g., <valid-connection-checker class-name="${valid.connection.checker}"></valid-connection-checker>.... also, thinking outside the box: Why do you need to remove the block if you can just hide it? :) e.g., <![CDATA[...]]> or  <!-- -->